# Make Next.js work with ract-native-web and styled-components

Tags: javascript, react-native, next.js, styled-components, react-native-web

I would like to use next.js, together with react-native-web and styled-components. I also got it kind of to work, but it's only rendering once for some reason. when visiting the route with the styled-component on it, it gives me this error:

```sh
./node_modules/styled-components/native/dist/styled-components.native.esm.js
Attempted import error: 'react-native' does not contain a default export (imported as 'reactNative').
Could not find files for /alternate in .next/build-manifest.json
ModuleDependencyError: "export 'default' (imported as 'reactNative') was not found in 'react-native'
```

I created a codesandbox with my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/BjoernRave/ReactNativeWebNext-Demo